# Display inline sums

Tags: math-mode, inline, displaystyle

I am writing my thesis and I have some sums which are inline, and others which are part of equations.

My questions is: is there a convention, an unwritten rule about how inline equations should be displayed? Which of the following is the "right" one for this kind of situation?

- `$T=\{\sum\nolimits_{i:e_{i} \in S_{j}} y_{i} = w_{j}\}$`
- `$T=\{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i:e_{i} \in S_{j}} y_{i} = w_{j}\}$`

In a book I have seen that all the inline sums are written with the first code, while the ones from equations with the second. Is this the correct way?

Comment: This may solicit primarily opinion-based answers and is not really a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: The second will make the line too high and deep, producing bad white stripes on the page; moreover the braces are too small. In the first `\nolimits` is redundant and `Probes` should really be `\operatorname{Probes}` or `\mathit{Probes}`.

Comment: @Werner: I'm sorry it's not a good fit, but I just wanted to know if there was a rule which said how the sums should be displayed; @egreg: Sorry, but `Probes` shouldn't be there; I forgot to erase it, but I will edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the correct way, because inline formulas shouldn't be too high. Theoretically, the distance between lines should be constant, which is impossible, when formulas are in the display style.

Comment: actually, the "rule" is not unwritten.  books for math compositors (originally for metal composition) do specify the "nolimits" convention for in-line sums and friends.  for more "contemporary" guidance, see [Mathematics into Type](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf), page 81.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to have `\sum\limits` for in line maths without increasing the interline spacing can be to :

1) slighly increase the value of  \baselinestretch, with the `setspace` package, say `\setspace{1.1}`.

2) use the medium sized math macros from the `nccmath` package (`\medop\sum\limits`).

3) use it moderately.

It's not so much the problem of sums, I must say, but I find the difference between textstyle and displaystyle fractions a startling contrast, and I usually prefer to use the `\mfrac` command.